# What order are zip files extracted in?

Tags: zip, unzip

Q: How do extraction programs work? How do they choose which files to extract first?

I extracted a zip file from Google Drive using an online extension. I was a bit surprised when the files came out to a mostly alphabetical order. I downloaded the files in an alphabetical order. So I tried to extract the files again locally from my computer. And again they came out to a mostly alphabetical, but different order. Why is that?

Comment: they are extracted in the same order they are added to the archive in, which depends on what program created the archive.

Comment: Related: [Order of extract-files when extracting more than one file](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/db363bf2/), [Specify an order while unzipping files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11449826/13253010)

Comment: What do you mean by "came out in ... order"?